# Recoving an unknown tree graph with knowledge of root node to leaf node distances

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics, computer-science

Imagine I have an unknown (undirected) tree graph, $G$, with some unknown number of nodes $||V||$.  However, I know the edge-length between nodes is of fixed size, $L_{edge} = 1$, and I have access to the set of distances $(d_1, ..., d_i, ..., d_M)$ between a root node, $v_{root}$, and leaf nodes, $l_i$.

When is this limited information sufficient to recover the structure of $G$, and for arbitrary $G$, beyond tree depth, what inferences might this allow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the question is a bit vague.  Anyhow.  You cannot recover the isomorphism type of the tree and you cannot recover the number of nodes.  There is a unique tree having that set of distances with the minimal number of nodes.  Namely, list the distances in increasing order
$d_1,\dots,d_M$.  Let $r$ be an end point of a path of length $d_1-1$.
Let $v$ be the other end point.
$r$ will be the root of the tree.  $v$ gets one child, which becomes the leave of distance $d_1$ from the root.  Also, use $v$ as the root the unique minimal tree for the distances $d_2-d_1+1,\dots,d_M-d_1+1$.

This recursive definition gives you the minimal tree with this set of distances.  This tree is a quotient of every tree with this set of distances.

Comment: On the other hand, if the distances between all pairs of leaves are given, the tree can be reconstructed.  This is an old result that is quite famous, but I don't remember who did it.  If the questioner intended that the distances be available for all possible root nodes, the answer would be different.

Comment: @Brendan McKay, no I didn't intend that... but I'm certainly interested in it!  If you happen to remember anything further about that old result, please do let me know.